# Starting a scheduled job in a c# mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've written a scheduled job that I want to execute every 5 minutes in a c# mvc application.  I'm not really sure how to get this method to start.  I've tried adding the method to my application_start in my global.asax but I see no "TimedJobRan" in the output window.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Web;

namespace Test.Jobs.Invoices
{
public class SendInvoiceEmail
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
        var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

        var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
        {
            Run();
        }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
    }

    public static void Run()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("TimedJobRan");
    }
}
}
```

Application_Start

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        ViewEngines.Engines.Insert(0, new DbDrivenViewEngine());
        Jobs.Invoices.SendInvoiceEmail.Main();
    }
```

Comment: You should look into using something like [hangfire](http://hangfire.io)

Comment: Yes, hangfire is amazing for these kind of jobs!

Comment: yes for Hangfire, EasyCRON, Azure Scheduler...LOADS of options out there

Comment: no single HTTP request will ever last long enough for your timer to trigger. a pure web app executes in short sharp bursts, starting up and shutting down every time there's a new request, it doesn't really keep running in the background. As the others have said, use one of these extension packages, or just build a separate Windows Service to execute these kinds of jobs.

Comment: Thanks for the honesty @ADyson you have truly helped me solve this problem.  Thanks also to the rest for their comments that actually helped.